# Передача переменной в spl_autoload_register

Tags: php, автозагрузка

**Application.php**

```
class Application extends Singleton{
 function start(){
   $object = application::get($controllerName, $folder);
 }
}
```

**Singleton.php**

```
abstract class Singleton{
 private static $all_objects = array();
 public static function get($className = false, $folder = false)
 {
   $Name = ($className === false)?get_called_class():$className;
   if(!isset(self::$all_objects[$Name]))
     self::$all_objects[$Name] = new $Name();
   $object = self::$all_objects[$Name];
   return $object;
 }
}
```

**Classes_autoload.php**

```
function controller_autoload($class_name){
  $file = FW.'controllers/'.$class_name.'.php';
  require_once ($file);
}

spl_autoload_register('controller_autoload');
```

`$folder` - это название подпапки в папке controllers. Насколько я понял, вызов `spl_autoload_register` происходит в момент `new $Name()`. Однако мне бы хотелось передать `$folder` в автозагрузчик класса, чтобы он стал вида

`$file = FW."controllers/$folder/".$class_name.'.php'` и искал файл в нужной папке.

**Вопрос:** Возможно ли это (если "да", то как туда передать эту переменную?) ?

P.S. Другие реализации поиска знаю, но интересует именно этот способ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не совсем то, что вы ислкали. Но самое близкое будет Анонимные функции:

http://php.net/manual/ru/functions.anonymous.php

Правда значение передается только один раз при создании. А не при вызове.

```
<?php                                                                                                                                                                                                              


$folder = '/classes/';                                                                                                                                                                                             

$autoloader = function ($className) use ($folder) {                                                                                                                                                                
    var_dump($className, $folder); die();                                                                                                                                                                          
};                                                                                                                                                                                                                 

spl_autoload_register($autoloader);                                                                                                                                                                                

$a = new A();
```

Comment: Думаю, мне стоит пересмотреть весь свой автозагрузчик, чтобы не использовать костыли)
А вам спасибо за отправную точку, думаю, это мне поможет.